# How to send selected href <a> tag value back to java method using velocity tempelate

Tags: java, html, jstl, velocity

Here is my piece of code:

```
     #foreach( $reportGroup in ${orgReport.reportGroupList})
        <br><tr><a href="${reportGroup.ReportGroupName}">${reportGroup.ReportGroupName}</a></tr><br>
     #end
```

It renders details like this

```
Monthly
Quarterly
Yearly
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, you use velocity to produce html markup in java which I presume you send to a client. What do you mean by **selected**? where does it happen?

Comment: I meant to say onClick but not select.

Comment: Here my question is if someone clicks on "Monthly" I would like send this value to java method based upon clicked value I will be rendering the next page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here my question is if someone clicks on "Monthly" I would like send this value to java method based upon clicked value I will be rendering the next page.

OK, your question is not primarily about velocity, but about how you handle requests from a web browser in a java based server environment, basically servlets.

When you click a `href` the browser sends - in normal circumstances -  a `GET` request to the server. The request contains parameters which you define in the `URL` you generate using velocity or any other view technology.

```
<a href="myResource?param1=foo&param2=bar>Click me!</a>
```

Here you will upon click send a request to the resource `myResource` along with the parameters `param1` and `param2` which respectively have the values `foo` and `bar`

You need to have a resource for example `periodHandler` which handles this kind of request, either a dedicated servlet which reads the request parameters and forwards to the next page or the next page itself. Then use it in you HTML-generation template, pass the values as parameter:

```
#foreach( $reportGroup in ${orgReport.reportGroupList})
    <br><tr>
        <a href="periodHandler?period=${reportGroup.ReportGroupName}">
            ${reportGroup.ReportGroupName}</a>
    </tr><br>
 #end
```

then you can do something like this in your java code

```
String period = request.getParameter("period");    
// period will contain either Monthly, Quarterly or Yearly
// do what ever you want with the value in the variable period
```

Comment: Makes lot of sense,In my project we have custom request handler.